# Properly using the HAVING clause in query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like the following,

```
SELECT a.day, a.user_id, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(b.days_since_login)) as days_since_login 
  FROM stats a, users b
  WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id
  AND a.active = 1
 GROUP BY 
  a.user_id
 HAVING 
  a.day = days_since_login
```

The problem I have is that if the `stats` table has more than one record for the user, zero rows return. If there is exactly one row, it'll return it.

I think my use of `HAVING` is incorrect here. The query planner seems to only filter based on the result set from the WHERE clause. Ideally, I'd have this illegal query:

```
SELECT a.day, a.user_id, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(b.days_since_login)) as days_since_login 
  FROM stats a, users b
  WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id
  AND a.active = 1
  AND a.day = days_since_login
 GROUP BY 
  a.user_id
```

But that's not possible.

Comment: `having` is the only way you could filter on the results of your `max` call - results of aggregate functions are only available AFTER all rows in a group have been processed. That means you can't use aggregate results in a `where` clause, because `where` is applied on a row-by-row basis, BEFORE aggregate results are available.

Comment: so `having` is clearly not what I need here and a rewrite of the query needs to happen

Comment: `days_since_login` is an aggregate result, so if you want to filter results based on those results, you **HAVE** to use a `having`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `GROUP BY`, any of the columns outside the grouped column will be fetched from an unpredictable row in the group. It won't search the group for rows that match the `HAVING` clause, because that filtering is done *after* grouping.

You need to join with a subquery that performs the grouping.

```
SELECT a.day, a.user_id, b.days_since_login
FROM stats AS a
JOIN (SELECT user_id, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(b.days_since_login)) as days_since_login 
      FROM users 
      GROUP BY user_id) AS b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.day = b.days_since_login
WHERE a.active = 1
```